# Issue with HTML select element in iOS 15

Tags: html, html-select, hybrid-mobile-app, ios15

On iOS 15 beta, when I tried to check my application, the select element is having issue. As when I clicked on select dropdown, the option list was not shown.

The error message was

> "Failed to present a context menu for configuration with identifier".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.